# ConfigurationError: No default database defined

Tags: python, mongodb

he creado una base de datos con el nombre introducido en el CODE, no obstante, me salta el siguiente error al ejecutar el CODE en Python:

```
raise ConfigurationError('No default database defined')

ConfigurationError: No default database defined




chatbot = ChatBot(
    "Experto_cruceros",

    storage_adapter='chatterbot.storage.MongoDatabaseAdapter',
    database_uri='mongodb://localhost:27017/',
    database='chatterbot_cruises_database',

    input_adapter="chatterbot.input.TerminalAdapter",

    output_adapter="chatterbot.output.OutputAdapter",
    output_format="text",

    logic_adapters=[
        {
            "import_path": "chatterbot.logic.BestMatch",
            "statement_comparison_function": "chatterbot.comparisons.levenshtein_distance",
            "response_selection_method": "chatterbot.response_selection.get_most_frequent_response"
        },
        {
            'import_path': 'chatterbot.logic.LowConfidenceAdapter',
            'threshold': 0.51,
            'default_response': 'Disculpa, no te he entendido bien, sólo soy experto en viajes. ¿Puedes ser más específico?.'
        },
        {
            'import_path': 'chatterbot.logic.SpecificResponseAdapter',
            'input_text': 'Quiero reservar un crucero',
            'output_text': 'Puedes reservarlo ahora en: https://www.logitravel.com/cruceros/'
        },
    ],

    preprocessors=[
        'chatterbot.preprocessors.clean_whitespace'
    ],

    read_only=True,
)
DEFAULT_SESSION_ID = chatbot.default_session.id
```

Answer (score 0):

debes usar de la siguiente forma:

```
database_uri='mongodb://localhost:27017/chatterbot_cruises_database',
```

Saludos cordiales,